How to fetch dynamic data in Next Js from database (eg. mongo DB) using Next Js API routes
I am currently building a small ecommerce shop and I am fetching data from mongo Db database to display to the user, the problem I have is that I am not getting the latest data from the database after I run the build command which seems to statically build each product data with the current data contained in the database and any updates on the data in the database does not reflect to the frontend. Here is my code in details (my code folder structure is in src>app)
page.tsx (src>app>page.tsx)
// src/app/page.tsx

import { ProductData } from "@/utils/interface";
import HomeSlider from "@/components/HomeSlider";
import CollectionHighlights from "@/components/CollectionHighlights";
import TopProducts from "@/components/TopProducts";

// fetch function to get data from the API
const fetchProducts = async (): Promise<{ [key: string]: ProductData }> => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products", {
    next: { revalidate: 60 }, 
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch products");
  }
  return res.json();
};

// Home component to serve the data to TopProduct component
const Home = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await fetchProducts();
    const products = Object.values(data);

    return (
      <main className="">
        <section className="px-3">
          <HomeSlider />
        </section>
        <section className="px-3 mt-10">
          <h1 className="text-center text-3xl sm:text-4xl font-extrabold text-slate-900 tracking-tight pb-5">
            Collections
          </h1>
          <CollectionHighlights />
        </section>
        <section className="px-3 mt-10">
          <h1 className="text-center text-3xl sm:text-4xl font-extrabold text-slate-900 tracking-tight pb-5">
            Top Products
          </h1>
          <TopProducts products={products} />
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching products:", error);
    return (
      <main className="">
        <section className="px-3">
          <HomeSlider />
        </section>
        <section className="px-3 mt-10">
          <h1 className="text-center text-3xl sm:text-4xl font-extrabold text-slate-900 tracking-tight pb-5">
            Collections
          </h1>
          <CollectionHighlights />
        </section>
        <section className="px-3 mt-10">
          <h1 className="text-center text-3xl sm:text-4xl font-extrabold text-slate-900 tracking-tight pb-5">
            Top Products
          </h1>
          <TopProducts products={[]} />{" "}
          {/* Provide empty array in case of error */}
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  }
};

export default Home;


route.ts (src>app>api>route.ts)
// src/app/api/route.ts

import { connect } from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig";
import { Product } from "@/modal/products";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

connect();

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find().exec();
    return NextResponse.json(products, {});
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Error occurred while fetching products" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}


All other code component seems to work well configaration to the database is sucessfull, problem lies in retriving the most recent data on each intial load or reload, the code seems to work well in local development with npm run dev but with npm run build all over sudden things changes to static on production any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance
below is the log information after running the command npm run build
$ npm run build

> rapido@0.1.0 build
> next build        

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.5
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...

   daisyUI 4.12.10
├─ ✔︎ 2 themes added            https://daisyui.com/docs/themes
╰─ ★ Star daisyUI on GitHub     https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui

 ✓ Compiled successfully

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
   Collecting page data  ..mongodb+srv://userAdmin:userPassword@userAdmin.xlllghj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=eCommerceshop
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (0/7)  [=   ]MongoDB conected successfuly
   Generating static pages (5/7)  [ ===]mongodb+srv://userAdmin:userPassword@userAdmin.xlllghj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=eCommerceshop
   Generating static pages (6/7)  [  ==]MongoDB conected successfuly
 ✓ Generating static pages (7/7)
 ✓ Collecting build traces    
 ✓ Finalizing page optimization

Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    1.65 kB         117 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          871 B          87.9 kB
├ ○ /api/products                        0 B                0 B
├ ○ /product                             137 B          87.2 kB
└ ƒ /product/[slug]                      395 B          87.4 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            87 kB
  ├ chunks/23-9061b51442bf377f.js        31.5 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-81f448b567f73d85.js  53.6 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)          1.86 kB


○  (Static)   prerendered as static content
ƒ  (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand

I am expecting to get the current data on each intial load time or on refresh

Have you tried using export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' in the problematic pages? You can check out more information regarding this here.

Hmm... let me check it out and see if it will work

Add cache: 'no-store', to you fetch, as per the docs: caching in next js

I don't really understand where the issue was but I went back to next documentation under data fetching and found out that next js has clearly stated that By default, fetch requests retrieve fresh data. Using it will cause a whole route to be dynamically rendered and data will not be cached. So what I did was a simple edit of my page component to client side rendering and included the useEffect hook like this
`const [topProducts, setTopProducts] = useState<ProductData[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTopProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/products");
        const result = await res.json();

        if (result.success) {
          setTopProducts(result.data);
        } else {
          console.error("Error fetching products:", result.message);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch top products", error);
      }
    };
    getTopProducts();
  }, []);
`

